# The interior of a connected set in $\mathbb R^k$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Is the interior of a connected set in $\mathbb R^k$ connected?

Comment: No, as answers below suggest. But, however you may want to prove that closure of connected sets are connected. (and that, interior of connected sets in $\Bbb{R}$ are connected.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. If $X\subset\mathbb R^2$ is the union of two closed disks of radius $1$, one with center at $(1;0)$ and another with center at $(-1;0)$, then $X$ is connected but its interior is not.

Comment: how do you show that the interior is both closed and open? It is eas to see by visualization, but is there a formal way to see this?

Comment: @user43901: Both closed and open in what space? The interior of $X$ is trivially closed and open in itself, and it is not closed in $X$.  Neither of those facts have bearing on why the interior is disconnected.  It is a union of $2$ disjoint nonempty open subsets.

Answer (score 12):

No. 
Let

$A_1=\{(x,y)|x\leq0,y\leq0\}$ (The third quadrant and the positive x-axis) and

$A_2=\{(x,y)|x\geq0,y\geq0\}$.(The first quadrant and the positive x-axis).

$A_1\cup A_2$ is connected. Their interior is the first and third quadrants.

Proof by visualization.

Answer (score 11):

Nope... Pick two tangent balls...

Comment: BTW: probably a better example is two non-touching disks connected by a segment of line.