# Closures and connected sets problem

Tags: real-analysis

> Are closures and interiors of connected sets always connected?

Interior definition: the interior of a s et is the union of all its open subsets

Concept question: What does it mean by closures of connected sets? How are closed sets related to connected sets?

Comment: If $A$ is any set in a topological space, it has a closure in that space. The question here could be paraphrased as follows: If $A$ is a connected set, are its closure and interior also connected sets?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141503/the-interior-of-a-connected-set-in-mathbb-rk
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678032/the-closure-of-a-connected-set-in-a-topological-space-is-connected